# How to continue the main code after executing start_event_loop in matplotlib

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, interaction

I have a plot code, which aims to:

**First:** plot one image with many red/blue dots inside.
**Second:** use mouse to select some point to be deleted and some to be change color
**Third:** update my dots database.

To achieve my goal, I intended to use `mpl_connect` and `start_event_loop`:

```
cid1=fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)
fig.canvas.start_event_loop(timeout = -1)
```

In my `onclick` event, I have if/else sentences:

if left click: the chosen point is to be deleted,
if right click: the chosen point is to be color changed,
if mid click: go out of the event code, and continue with my code.

```
elif event.button == 2:
    print("exit and continue")
    fig.canvas.stop_event_loop
    fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid1)
```

However, when I run this code, and press mid-button on the figure, the code can not continue executing.

Are there any functions, which can make the flow go back to the main code?

Here is the code:

```
import ...

def onclick(event):
    if event.button == 1:
        get click axis and delete the points in list
    elif event.button == 3:
        get click axis and change the points attribute in list
    elif event.button == 3:
        print("exit and continue")
        fig.canvas.stop_event_loop
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid1)

if __name__== "__main__":
plt.ion()

//my data reading code

fig =  plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.imshow(data,origin="lower")
dot.append(ax1.plot(peak[i]["coord"][0],peak[i]["coord"][1],color(peak[i]["atom"])+"o",markersize=1))   //plot dots

cid1=fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)
fig.canvas.start_event_loop(timeout = -1)

// I want to first do the clicking, and continue my remaining codes here after.
print("continue")
```

Comment: When calling `plt.show()` you automatically start the event loop and show the figure. When closing the figure window you automatically jump back to the python code. So I wonder why not use the figure closure as the point to continue with the rest of the code?

Comment: I want to start the event loop manually and close the event loop manually. So I tried start event loop and close event loop. however, after close event loop executed, I cannot go back to my "main stream" code. I dont know why.

The terminal stops at
“exit and continue”

when I close the figure,
error appears:
"tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed"